# Internal Error When Updating Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, updates, auto-update

Every time I try to update Android Studio it downloads and then this pops up:

```
Internal error. Please report to http://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.io.IOException: Cannot restart application: Can't obtain static newInstance method for class com.sun.jna.Structure
    at com.intellij.util.Restarter.scheduleRestart(Restarter.java:76)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.installPatch(Main.java:184)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:73)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't obtain static newInstance method for class com.sun.jna.Structure
    at com.sun.jna.Native.initIDs(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:135)
    at com.intellij.util.Restarter.restartOnWindows(Restarter.java:106)
    at com.intellij.util.Restarter.scheduleRestart(Restarter.java:67)
    ... 2 more

2014-11-06 14:31:23 [Patch] Original patch exists: C:\Users\Aidan\AppData\Local\Temp\jetbrains.patch.jar.androidstudio
2014-11-06 14:31:23 [Patch] Restarted cmd: [C:\Users\Aidan\AppData\Local\Temp\VistaLauncher8848951449880199676.exe, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\bin\java, -Xmx500m, -classpath, C:\Users\Aidan\AppData\Local\Temp\jetbrains.patch.jar.androidstudio_copy;C:\Users\Aidan\AppData\Local\Temp\log4j.jar.AndroidStudio_copy, -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\Aidan\AppData\Local\Temp\, -Didea.updater.log=C:\Users\Aidan\.AndroidStudioBeta\system\log, -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel, com.intellij.updater.Runner, install, D:\Android Studio]
2014-11-06 14:31:23 Exception: java.io.IOException: Cannot restart application: Can't obtain static newInstance method for class com.sun.jna.Structure
```

I always end up downloading the update from the site, deleting the original, then extracting the new version alongside the sdk folder. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Sort of..

Adding the line `-Djna.nosys=true` to the studio.vmoptions file in the /bin folder fixed my problem and I am now updated. I found the solution from here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78656

Comment: I have now done this twice to be able to update to Ver. 0.9.2

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution

First, you should delete 2 folders C:\Users\USER_NAME\.android, C:\Users\USER_NAME\.AndroidStudio And  delete all files in C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Temp

Second, remove and re-install Android Studio

this way works perfectly